Instance segmentation of very close objects of the same class
I have a project where I have to detect and segment a variable number of cross section layers of a given material. Each layer is right above or below of the other one and the bounding boxes overlap on each other. Unfortunately, I cannot share the images in my dataset but the problem is very similar to the question here. The images are also very similar to mine albeit my layers are much more closer to each other.

I find that the question has not been answered and also other attempts such as this and that one, have not really come to a conclusion. Seeing that some years have passed since those questions have been asked. I would like to see if there are some better ways of solving this problem. Are there better PyTorch libraries/architectures/approaches to solve this problem? Is there a possible better way to train on this type of images? Better loss functions to consider? Is this problem generally difficult to solve?
What I have done so far:

Labeled 25 images of layer cross sections (I think this should be enough to get a first glance on the performace, seeing that the images are very similar).
Used the Detectron2 library to train on pretrained Mask R-CNN based models.
Performed different types of dataset augmentations
Performed a hyper-parameter optimization

The result of all this was an instance segmentation on par with the image on the right of the example.
